# Handler defined with document.on deleted when object deleted from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, memory-leaks, single-page-application

I have some severe memory leaks on my SPA. I managed to localize where the leak is, but I can't fix it. I have a code like this :

```
$(document).on("click.widget", ".glyphicon-collapse-down", function (e) {
    var contentElement = $(e.target).closest(".widget").find(".widget-body");
    $(e.target)
        .removeClass("glyphicon-collapse-down")
        .addClass("glyphicon-collapse-up");
    kendo.fx(contentElement).expand("vertical").stop().play();
});
```

I can generate widgets over time on my single page, so I need the buttons to have a handler even if they don't exist yet (every widget come with a button group). When I switch from the current page to another, I delete everything from the page and load a new page with an ajax request. And here is appears the memory leak. I suspect that it might lies in the fact that the handlers are not deleted properly.

**EDIT :** The leak becomes very smaller when I don't include this script in the app :

```
//expand the widget
$(document).on("click.widget", ".glyphicon-collapse-down", function (e) {
    var contentElement = $(e.target).closest(".widget").find(".widget-body");
    $(e.target)
        .removeClass("glyphicon-collapse-down")
        .addClass("glyphicon-collapse-up");
    kendo.fx(contentElement).expand("vertical").stop().play();
});
//collapse the widget
$(document).on("click.widget", ".glyphicon-collapse-up", function (e) {
    var contentElement = $(e.target).closest(".widget").find(".widget-body");
    $(e.target)
        .removeClass("glyphicon-collapse-up")
        .addClass("glyphicon-collapse-down");
    kendo.fx(contentElement).expand("vertical").stop().reverse();
});
//remove the widget and updating the layout accordingly
$(document).on("click.widget", ".glyphicon-remove", function (e) {
    var contentElement = $(e.target).closest(".widget");
    var ancestor = $(contentElement).parent();
    var rightColumn = $("#right-column");
    var mainColumn = $("#main-column");
    kendo.unbind(contentElement);
    kendo.destroy(contentElement);
    $(contentElement).fadeOut().remove();
//    //Widget layout modification on remove
    if ((rightColumn.items().length - 1 == 0) && (ancestor.attr("id") == "right-column")) {
        if (mainColumn.items().length == 1) {
            $("#main-column").removeClass("col-lg-6").hide().addClass("col-lg-12").fadeIn();
        }
        else if (mainColumn.items().length > 1) {
            var firstWidget = mainColumn.items().last();
            $(firstWidget).hide().prependTo("#right-column").fadeIn();
        }
    }
    if ((mainColumn.items().length - 1 == 0) && (ancestor.attr("id") == "main-column")) {
        if (rightColumn.items().length == 1) {
            $("#right-column").removeClass("col-lg-6").hide().addClass("col-lg-12").fadeIn();
        }
        else if (rightColumn.items().length > 1) {
            var firstWidget = rightColumn.items().last();
            $(firstWidget).hide().prependTo("#main-column").fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
//Enable the widget fullscreen
$(document).on("click.widget", ".widget-fullscreen-on", function (e) {
    var contentElement = $(e.target).closest(".widget");
    contentElement.addClass("fullscreen");
    $(e.target)
            .removeClass("glyphicon-resize-full")
            .removeClass("widget-fullscreen-on")
            .addClass("glyphicon-resize-small")
            .addClass("widget-fullscreen-off");
});
//Disable the widget fullscreen
$(document).on("click.widget", ".widget-fullscreen-off", function (e) {
    var contentElement = $(e.target).closest(".widget");
    contentElement.removeClass("fullscreen");
    $(e.target)
            .removeClass("glyphicon-resize-small")
            .removeClass("widget-fullscreen-off")
            .addClass("glyphicon-resize-full")
            .addClass("widget-fullscreen-on");
});
//Inserts a widget into the page content and modifies the layout accordingly
function insertWidget(jtext) {
    jtext.attr("id", "");
    if (($('#main-column').items().length == 0) && ($('#right-column').items().length == 0)) {
        if ($("#main-column").hasClass("col-lg-12")) {
            $(jtext).hide().prependTo('#main-column').fadeIn();
        }
        else if ($("#right-column").hasClass("col-lg-12")) {
            $(jtext).hide().prependTo('#right-column').fadeIn();
        }
    }
    else if ($("#main-column").hasClass("col-lg-12")) {
        $("#main-column").removeClass("col-lg-12").addClass("col-lg-6");
        $(jtext).hide().prependTo('#right-column').fadeIn();
    }
    else if ($("#right-column").hasClass("col-lg-12")) {
        $("#right-column").removeClass("col-lg-12").addClass("col-lg-6");
        $(jtext).hide().prependTo('#main-column').fadeIn();
    }
    else if ($('#right-column').items().length < $('#main-column').items().length) {
        $(jtext).hide().prependTo('#right-column').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $(jtext).hide().prependTo('#main-column').fadeIn();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible, but be aware that you are only defining one handler when using this method (on the `document`) so unless you have *a lot* of event handlers defined, or are leaving the browser open for several days it's unlikely this is the source of your leak. You could namespace each pages event handlers and remove them all when the page changes, eg `.off('.home')`

Comment: Thanks for the information. I only have 5-6 handlers and they are defined for the whole document with document.on . But I didn't hthink that it was in fact a single handler for everybody.

Comment: Yep, that's how event delegation works. It only puts the event handler on the primary selector (the `document` in your cases) and relies on the event bubbling up the DOM from the targeted element(s)

Comment: What I don't understand is that when I delete all these handlers, the won't leak anymore when I delete the content and load a new one via ajax. I can edit my question if you want more code.

Comment: "*I managed to localize where the leak is*" - How? Where is it? Please share details.

Comment: I edited my answer and added the code

Comment: What is `jtext`? And where do you call `insertWidget`? I see you're doing `kendo.unbind`/`destroy`, where are you setting this up?

Comment: jtext is the widget that is going to be inserted in the page, insertwidget is called in another file when you click on a button that triggers an ajax request : `success: function (text) {
                var jtext = $(text);
                jtext = jtext.find('#field-comments');
                insertWidget(jtext);
            }`
I tried to delete the kendo thing but it changed nothing.